# Where does the bit come from when capture the bits to scan cell in jtag Capture-DR stage?

Tags: jtag

Based on the Jtag stage diagram, before Jtag shifts the bits (Shift-DR) the scan cell needs to capture the bits first (Capture-DR). Where does the bit come from? It is from some test patterns (which consists of 0s and 1s) and Jtag loads them via digital pins during the capture-DR stage?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably noticed that the FSM path for IR column and DR column are the same, and basically involve going through Capture exactly once, Shift zero or more times, and Update exactly once. Pause and Exit* state are just there for state machine management.

Main concept of JTAG TAP is to expose two scan paths:

- Instruction, which is a fixed register with TAP-dependent meaning,
- Data, which is actually multiplexed, depending on the instruction currently loaded.

For the TAP, going through the Instruction or Data shifting state sequence implies:

- preparing bits that will be outputted to TDO (Capture),
- shifting bits in and out (Shift),
- doing something with shifted-in bits (Update).

On Update-IR, what you shifted as instruction is written to the Instruction register.

A given instruction set to IR implies:

- A data shift register length,
- what TAP loads in data shift register when going through Capture-DR,
- what TAP does with contents of data shift register when going through Update-DR,
- what TAP does when in Run-Test/Idle.

Let's take three examples:

- If IR is IDCODE (assuming TAP implements IDCODE), DR is 32 bits, going through Capture-DR initializes data shift register to chip's ID Code.
- If IR is BYPASS, DR is 1 bit, going through Capture-DR initializes data shift register to "0" (mandated by standard).
- If IR is EXTEST (or SAMPLE), going through Capture-DR loads the shift register with the current state of the pins (what is called "boundary scan register" or BSR). What corresponds to each bit is defined in BSDL definition for the chip.

Chip manufacturer may defined more instructions with other scan lengths and behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. If I understand correctly, IR (instruction register) helps to shift the instructions (IDCODE,BYPASS, EXTEST, etc) and these instructions decide the behavior of DR. If the instruction is EXTEST, during the Capture-DR state, all the bits defined in the BSDL starts to shift to digital pins (distribute to different pins) before it moves to next state Shift DR

Comment: And If IR is IDCODE, it needs to shift 32 bits. Does that mean there are reserved 32 digital pins (exclude jtag pins) to capture the bits to scan the cell?

Comment: IDCODE DR capture value is a constant. It does not need to be connected to actual pins of the chip. Internal constant is sufficient.

Comment: I see, so IDCODE is to shift bits information from idcode register to IDO.

Comment: How about SOC testing? During the testing, we need to shift in some test patterns (0&1) to the chip and compare the results. Does the pattern actually define in the BSDL?

Comment: BSDL gives you mapping between boundary scan register and pins. What you do with pins (in or out, value, check) is dependent on the board netlist and your test strategy.